# Transaction log growth 35% at the time of rebuilding index

Tags: sql, sql-server, transaction-log

I have a small database around 3 GB and the index are highly fragmented. There are few index which are 97% fragmented. In order to reduce the fragmentation, I started rebuilding the index. But after rebuilding the index, I find that this activity generated lots of transaction log. My transaction log grow around 35-40% more just because of rebuilding the index.

I have some mirroring and log shipping set ON on this database. Now the question is how can I restrict SQL Server that it will not generate the log for index rebuild activity or generate less log for these type of activity

Notes:

1. I have gone through some websites where people have suggested to put the database in simple and bulk recovery mode and do these kind of activity. I can not do this, I have to change a lot of things for that.
2. I am already following the Microsoft's thumb rule of rebuilding or reorganizing the index i.e >=30% fragmentation rebuilding and <30% reorganize .

Comment: is it possible for you to create/alter indinzes in this database? Maybe there's something wrong with that. Is it one particular index or many/all of the indizes that fragement so bad?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.  SQL Server has to grow the log file in order to have enough space to hold the transaction for the index rebuild operation.  The entire index rebuild operation has to be able to fit into the transaction log and it has to remain there until the command is mirrored to the partner and then backed up.

Do not change the recovery model, this will break your log backup chain.